# Is it possible to change inner css from java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have jquery menu in application, and on selecting of particular element; its background color gets change.

Color is changing according to css. We are designing "Theme" and are trying to change color of css dynamically using Javascript, so that on selecting menu; its color will be changed. But, we are not getting well way to do it.

Following is the css: -

```
.mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a
{
    background: #1971AA;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Create a class in your CSS, and use jQuery's `addClass()` method to assign it to the elements you require.

Comment: Stylesheets *can* be dynamically manipulated - but this is not the appropriate method for this,

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed number of values for the background, then use classes like this:

```
.theme1 .mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a {background-color: #f99;}
.theme2 .mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a {background-color: #ff9;}
.theme3 .mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a {background-color: #fff;}
```

If not, use inline styles, targetting the parent and giving an `inherit`:

```
$(".mmenu").css("background-color", "#ff9");
```

And in the CSS:

```
.mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a {background-color: inherit;}
```

Comment: Kindly correct me, if I am wrong.Theme 1 to 3, we will define in some css file and on selecting of particular theme, we will load it. And because of inherit property; it would work fine for all selected menu item.But, How will we load into memory?

Comment: But, How will we load into memory?

Comment: @Worldprogram Add it into CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Try css method:

```
$(".mmenu li.mmenu-selected > a").css({"background": "#1971AA", "color":"#FFFFFF"});
```

Comment: Note: sets css style on the selected elements; does not change the stylesheet. Also not very 'clean' in terms of adding style decorations.